# Can reflected XSS (cross site scripting) attack happen on a REST API which serves non HTML response

Tags: security, spring-security, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

Can reflected XSS (cross site scripting) attack happen on a REST API which takes in a XML request payload, serves a XML response. There is no html content in the request or response.

I have gone through quite some documentation on XSS, now I am of the opinion that this doesn't apply to a REST API which doesn't serve html content, is this understanding correct?
We are however doing validation on the request received to check if there are any kind of tags (<>) in the input, & few other business level validations.

Few points about our service,

1. Our REST APIs don’ t receive or respond with HTML data.
2. We are not getting any input or request directly from an end user
   (possibility of an attacker comes majorly from malicious end users )
3. We are not sending XML responses directly to end users / HTML rendering
   system (browser) where the chances of XSS is highest.
4. We take the request & pass on the response to services internal to our
   enterprise & trusted (partners).
5. The XML response we send is used to just read the values embedded in a
   non-html env (these are trusted services that are reading our responses).

How much is the risk of an XSS in this case?

(The reason behind this query is we are getting a checkmarx high severity error where in it suggests we are prone to reflected XSS, and I am thinking this might be a false positive in our case. We are using a spring boot application.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly depends on the response `content-type`. As long as it's something like `applicatiin/xml` or `text/xml` (and not `text/html` or `application/xhtml`), the api itself is not vulnerable to xss, because a modern browser will not run the script even if displayed.

Note though that it might still be vulnerable to xml injection, and if Checkmarx found it as xss, there probably is some kind of possible injection. Make sure that it's not possible for a user to create xml tags or attributes in the response. The way to do that is very similar to how xss is prevented. Note though that you do not need to html encode user input when writing it to the xml as it's not html, but you need to xml encode values.

Also note that validating input is nice, but in general, injection attacks are prevented by context-aware output encoding, ie. applying the appropriate encoding type to values, xml attributes and so on. Many times you cannot fully achieve this on the input side. (Input validation still makes sense and you should be doing that too, but injections are best prevented by output encoding.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
Our response content type is application/json, application/xml.
Springboot is taking care of input validation & see if there are any scripts injected in the XML request body. We also have some validations from our side.

On the response xml content encoding, I am assuming you meant encoding these characters, `<, >, ", ', &` - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/XML/How_to_encode_a_string_for_an_XML_attribute_using_Java.htm. Right?

Comment: I tried adding encoding to my response using a filter servlet.
Now in the response I see encoded characters, as expected.
`&lt;?xml version=&#34;1.0&#34; encoding=&#34. . . . . `
Viewing this is HTML shows the correct xml,
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding= . . . . .`

But our clients are another service who access our response from code, they will be expecting a normal XML as per the contract & they will receive a encoded XML.
One way is we ask them to decode, but that we want to avoid. Any other way to overcome this & not have client make any changes but still they can get the normal XML?

Comment: No no, you can't just encode the whole result. :) You need to encode each value in the xml that you do not trust, one by one. It depends on how exactly the xml is made, where data comes from etc. As a rule of thumb, any data from a user is untrusted.

Comment: I understand your point now. I have edited the question & added few points describing our system. Do you see any risk of XSS in this kind of system?

Comment: XSS no, XML injection yes. I don't think it's best to model the systems you read from as trusted, they can be compromised, they might receive user input and so on. I think you should be building resilient systems, with defense in depth, and encode every non-static value in your xmls. This will save you a lot of headache going forward, and not just security-wise. On the other hand, whatever way you use to create the xml, that might already apply appropriate encodings. Try what if a value contains a < character? If you can create a tag, you should encode. If it gets encoded, then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a XSS attack can happen even in a service that serves only XML. If you include the following in a XML document which is loaded by the browser, the script will be executed:

```xml
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">alert("XSS")</script>
```

This can be a security vulnerability even if the service is not meant to be used in a browser. This is because an attacker can cause a victim's browser to load the XML document with the injected javascript (for example using an iframe) an run his malicious script on your site. This can have various consequences:

- If another service is running on the exact same domain, the attacker can gain access to it.
- The attacker can also set cookies for every parent domain (except TLD and some other exceptions), which might be used to attempt to exploit other servers.
- The attacker can use it for phishing to present a legitimate url in the address bar.

It's also possible that an XML injection could be used to trick some other service into doing something unexpected. Sometimes other services pass user input into APIs without any validation. A poorly written service might expose the XSS on a normal HTML website.

In any case i would advise you to fix any XSS vulnerability you find, even if you think it's not exploitable.